# Breusch-Pagan test for Homoscedasticity Value Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels

I create a linear model of the data, then the residuals in which to run the test. I get an error saying it needs a constant.

```
import  statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.stats.api as sms
```

Create a Linear Model

```
x = heights['AM_Height']
y = heights['PM_Height']
model = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
```

Test for Homoscedasticity

```
pred_val = model.fittedvalues.copy()
true_val = heights['PM_Height'].values.copy()
residual = true_val - pred_val
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,2.5))
_ = ax.scatter(residual, pred_val)
```

```
sms.diagnostic.het_breuschpagan(residual, heights[['AM_Height']])
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 sms.diagnostic.het_breuschpagan(residual, heights[['AM_Height']])

File C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\stats\diagnostic.py:792, in het_breuschpagan(resid, exog_het, robust)
    724 r"""
    725 Breusch-Pagan Lagrange Multiplier test for heteroscedasticity
    726 
   (...)
    789    heteroskedasticity". Journal of Econometrics 17 (1): 107–112.
    790 """
    791 x = array_like(exog_het, "exog_het", ndim=2)
--> 792 _check_het_test(x, "The Breusch-Pagan")
    793 y = array_like(resid, "resid", ndim=1) ** 2
    794 if not robust:

File C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\stats\diagnostic.py:717, in _check_het_test(x, test_name)
    712 x_max = x.max(axis=0)
    713 if (
    714     not np.any(((x_max - x.min(axis=0)) == 0) & (x_max != 0))
    715     or x.shape[1] < 2
    716 ):
--> 717     raise ValueError(
    718         f"{test_name} test requires exog to have at least "
    719         "two columns where one is a constant."
    720     )

ValueError: The Breusch-Pagan test requires exog to have at least two columns where one is a constant.
```

Comment: Try:  `x = sm.add_constant(heights['AM_Height'])` and `het_test = sms.diagnostic.het_breuschpagan(residual, x)`

Comment: Is your question why it needs a constant?